# CollectionView navigationController?.pushViewController() does nothing with no error

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode10

I have created a CollectionView and I want to open a ViewController with specific details depending on which row was clicked.(I'm not using a storyboard this is all done programatically).

[image]

I've looked at the documentation and I am trying to use the override function `didSelectItemAt` and `navigationController?.pushViewController()` but nothing seems to happen. No error or anything? See my Code:

**(CollectionViewController)**
[image]

**(ViewController)**
[image]

I've also tried supplying the layout to the viewcontroller but no luck. It is clearly accepting the click function of each row because it prints out to the log fine:

[image]

Any help to what i've missed here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try printing navigation controller stack, check if navigationcontroller is nil or not.?

Comment: Ah yeah, navigation controller prints out as nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure in your `TabBarController`, the controller is initialized as `navigationController`

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: YourController())
    viewControllers = [vc1, vc2]
}
```

before you put it into `viewControllers` array, so that you could call `navigationController?.pushViewController()` in `vc1`

Another thing: Make sure you give a flow layout when initializing `CollectionViewController` before push, like so:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let detailVC = PlaceDetailController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
detailVC.place = ... // Pass value here
navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```